# Opcode for negative jump

Tags: assembly, x86, opcode, shellcode

I'm trying to create some shellcode where I need to jump back (a negative jump). 
I want to jump 2400 bytes back. And this is the opcode I use:

```
\x90\xE9\x98\xef
```

This is first a `nop` and then a near jump to -4200. 0xef98 = -4200 (at least what I think). 
However in the debugger it looks like this:

```
0:142> t
eax=00000000 ebx=7c9032a8 ecx=02a8eb70 edx=7c9032bc esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=02a8ffac esp=02a8ea94 ebp=02a8eaa8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
02a8ffac 90              nop
0:142> t
eax=00000000 ebx=7c9032a8 ecx=02a8eb70 edx=7c9032bc esi=00000000 edi=00000000
eip=02a8ffad esp=02a8ea94 ebp=02a8eaa8 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
02a8ffad e998efcccc      jmp     cf75ef4a
```

As expected first a nop and then a jmp but the address to jump to is not what I expected (something like `jmp 02A8EF45` would be what I had in mind).
Can anyone see what I did wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me as though you're coding for a jump with a 32-bit offset. Look at the generated code bytes (the last line of your sample):

```
02a8ffad e998efcccc      jmp     cf75ef4a
```

The processor is going to use the value `0xccccef98` as the jump offset. If you want a 16-bit offset, you have to specify it explicitly. Or (it's been a while), you'll have to provide a  32-bit operand.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Changed to a 32-bit operand and it works. How can I specify that I want 16-bit operand? I found in Intel Manual vol 2: "When using relative offsets, the opcode (for short vs. near jumps) and the operand-size attribute (for near relative jumps) determines the size of the target operand (8, 16, or 32 bits)." Short jump have another opcode but I don't get how to distinguish between 16 and 32 bit operand.

Comment: @jortan: You put a 0x66 prefix byte in front of the instruction. So it would be `0x66 0xe9 0x98 0xfc`. How you code that depends on the assembler. Something like `jmp short` or perhaps `jmp near`. You'll need to look that up.

Answer (score 4):

`e9` means `jmp rel32` so you need a **dword** operand, two bytes isn't enough:

```
jmp $-4200    ; e9 93 ef ff ff
```

It's often easier to use an assembler when you're trying these things out:

```
$ cat shellcode.asm
bits 32
jmp $-4200
$ nasm -o shellcode shellcode.asm
$ hexdump -C shellcode
...
```

Comment: Yes, -2400 was a typo. Thanks also for the nasm tip!

Comment: Isn't e9 is also "jmp rel16"? I'm looking in Intel Manual Vol 2A and can't really see any difference for using E9 with 16-bit operand and 32-bit operand. In my case 16-bit operand obviously did not work, 32-bit operand did. How can the 16-bit operand be used?

Comment: `e9` is `jmp rel16` in 16-bit mode ("real" mode), and `jmp rel32` in 32-bit mode ("protected" mode). There is unfortunately no special opcode for `jmp rel16` in 32-bit mode so you cannot use that at all. `eb` is a short jump (`jmp rel8`) but that won't be enough in your case.

Comment: my bad, I completely forgot about the **size override** prefix! As Jim mentioned you can do `jmp rel16` exactly the way you want to if you simply add a `66` prefix to the opcode, i.e. `66 e9 93 3f`. That prefix tells the CPU to decode the next instruction as a 16-bit instruction. It is usually used for things like `mov ax, dx` but works fine for jumps too.

Answer (score 2):

Working to make a new ASM Compiler and 66 prefix seem to just not work for me.

[66 E9 XX XX] always cause GPF.

It seem you can't use 66 for JXX (JMP, JNE, JBE etc..)

Check out PUSH:

```
6A 12          = PUSH 12    (IM8 as a 32bits)
68 34 12 00 00 = PUSH 1234  (32 bits)

66 6A 00       = PUSH 0     (IM8 as a 16 Bits)
66 68 34 12    = PUSH 1234  (16 bits)
```

You notice there is also no OPCode to push a 16 bits Immediate as a 32bits =D

My guess now is Martin was right at first, you can't use it bc it would confuse the CPU with REAL MODE.